# VBA Returning the wrong cell containing the maximum value

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to find the maximum value in the entire column E. The code below returns a row number but it is not the row which contains the maximum value. Kind of at a loss as to what to fix here. I was able to get it working by using Index & Match but would like to get it working this way. My spreadsheet is here:

[image]

```
Sub MonthHighestDemand()
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim MaxVal As Long
    ' Long rounds, double leaves it alone

    Set wsData = Worksheets("DATA")
    Set rng = Range("E:E")

    MaxVal = WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)
    Set MaxCell = rng.Find(what:=MaxVal, LookIn:=xlValues)
    mDRow = MaxCell.Row

    MsgBox mDRow
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set rng = wsData.Range("E:E")` and use: `mDRow = Application.Match(Application.Max(rng),rng,0)`

Comment: `Dim MaxVal As Double` - Does that fix it? Because `Long` type can't handle decimals and you are searching for non decimal rounded number which may exist in numerous cells.

Comment: @Scott Holtzman I've tried this to no avail sadly.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with your code (except I changed `xlValues` to `xlFormulas`. Please be more specific about your problem.  Perhaps you are not seeing the maxvalue on your worksheet due to not seeing enough of the decimals.